# Create on a CDialog derived class returns 0 with VS2015 CLR, worked fine in VC++ 6

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, mfc, cdialog, visual-studio-6

I'm trying migrate a VC++ 6 based code to work with VS2015 CLR.
I have major functionality working, but UI has some things missing.

I have traced this issue to failures of SubclassDlgItem due to NULL HWnd for parent CWnd. It is NULL, because Create on a CDialog derived parent class returns 0 at following in dlgcore.cpp

```
if (hWnd != NULL && !(m_nFlags & WF_CONTINUEMODAL))
    {
        ::DestroyWindow(hWnd);
        hWnd = NULL;
    }
```

m_nFlags = 256 (Defined as #define WF_OLECTLCONTAINER  0x0100  // some descendant is an OLE control in afxwin.h)

And hWnd is not NULL, but '::CreateDialogIndirect() did NOT create the window (ie. due to error in template) and returns NULL' as per Microsoft comments

Following is the code for parent CWnd

```
CreateEx(
            WS_EX_NOPARENTNOTIFY,
            NULL,
            "MainClient",
            WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS,
            0, 0,       // Locate at upper left corner of client area
            1, 1,       // Initial size doesn't matter - will be sized to fit parent
            parent->GetSafeHwnd(),
            NULL
        );
```

Following is the code for CDialog creation

```
m_pMainDialog = new CxMainDialog();
m_pMainDialog->Create(IDD_MAIN_DIALOG, this);
```

Below is the CxMainDialog constructor

```
CxMainDialog::CxMainDialog(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialog(CxMainDialog::IDD, pParent)
{

    //{{AFX_DATA_INIT(CxMainDialog)
        // NOTE: the ClassWizard will add member initialization here
    //}}AFX_DATA_INIT
}
```

How may I get this to work?

Comment: Thanks, updated 'feel' with specifics.

Comment: Clarification: MFC comes with sources, you can step into them and check what exactly fails *during creation*.

Comment: Yes, DestroyWindow is being called inside dlgcore.cpp, because m_nFlags = 256.

Comment: Did you check creation of the parent window? You did not pass a class name to CreateEx, so that probably fails. When using MFC and even if you don't want to check for errors during release please check them at debug (e.g. by using `VERIFY` macro: `VERIFY(CreateEx(...)`).

Comment: I have checked it manually before, passes and has a valid HWnd.

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666927/cwndcreatedlgindirect-leaves-m-hwnd-null

Comment: Thanks, let me try this and get back here.

Comment: Suggestion from that question did not work, now I have deleted all the controls from my dialog and while creating an empty dialog, now OnInitDialog is being called and fails at HRSRC hDlgInit = ::FindResource(hInst, lpszResourceName, RT_DLGINIT); with hDlgInit = NULL

Comment: Thanks @WernerHenze, this issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was resolved by fixing the dialog template by removing ActiveX controls causing the problem while Create. I created a duplicate dialog and emptied it to test that Create is successful.